# Upgraded to iOS 11 iPhone 5S won't connect to data

Tags: iphone, cellular-data, ios, wifi-calling

I have an iPhone 5S that I upgraded to iOS 11 and now it will no longer connect to data when I have Wi-Fi and Bluetooth turned off.

My Carrier is T-Mobile and I have Wi-Fi Calling enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable Wi-Fi Calling. When you disable Wi-Fi and have Wi-Fi Calling enabled it wont connect to cellular data. Not sure if this is related to how T-Mobile Wi-Fi Calling is, or if it is an iOS issue.

Steps:

- Goto Settings
- Cellular
- Wi-Fi Calling
- **Toggle Off** Wi-Fi Calling on This iPhone
- Go Back to Cellular and **Toggle On** Cellular Data.

Answer (score 0):

Try to reset your network setting from your iPhone 5s by going to: Settings > General > Reset > Reset Network Settings.